# BLE device awareness of the IOS mobile Presence and Absence

Tags: ios, background, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are developing a bluetooth low energy device for a home automation application.
We are facing a major questioning for which we need help.

Here is the use case:
The device needs to have the awareness of the user IOS phone presence or absence in the house.
The BLE devices are working on peripheral role, the IOS should therefore work on central role.
The IOS App is mainly running in background mode.

For the presence detection awareness , we think it can be obvious: the phone whenever entering into the range will discover the device and initiate a connection to inform its presence to the device.

However we are struggling to find the absence detection method.
How shall we implement the absence detection awareness so the device would know when the user is not at home?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you ,

During initial sync of your iOS device with peripheral basically when you are writing configuration settings on the BLE you can save the iphone's UUID of the user on ble but still you have to get the UUID of iPhone when user is in the range.